# zf2 captcha validation security issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, captcha

I am using zf2 captcha in a form:
in controller :

```
public function loginAction() {
        $loginForm = new LoginForm ( );
        if ($this->getRequest ()->isPost ()) {
            $postedValues = $this->getRequest ()->getPost ();
            $loginForm->setData ( $postedValues );
            if ($loginForm->isValid ()) {
                echo 'valid';

            } else {
                echo 'invalid';
            }
        } 
    }
    $view ['loginForm'] = $loginForm;
    return new ViewModel ( $view );
}
```

in my loginForm I have :

```
public function __construct($adapter) {
    parent::__construct ();
    $this->setAttribute ( 'method', 'post' );
    $this->setAttribute ( 'name', 'loginForm' );
    $inputFilter = new InputFilter ();
    $factory = new Factory ();
    $captchaImage = new CaptchaImage(  array(
            'font' => dirname(__DIR__).'/../../../../public/fonts/arial.ttf',
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 75,
            'dotNoiseLevel' => 40,
            'lineNoiseLevel' => 3 ,
            'wordLen' => 5
        )
    );
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
        'name' => 'captcha',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Security Question',
            'captcha' => $captchaImage,
        ),
    ));
    $submit = new Element\Submit ( 'submit' );
    $submit->setValue ( _ ( 'Login' ) )->setAttributes ( array (
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
            'class' => 'btn btn-default' 
    ) );
    $this->add ( $submit );
    }
```

and in my phtml file :

```
if(isset($this->loginForm)){    
    $form = $this->loginForm;
    $form->prepare();
    var_dump($form->getMessages());
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    ?>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <?php 
        foreach ($form as $element) {

            echo '<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">
                    '.
                    _($element->getLabel()).
                '</label>'
                    .$this->formElement($element).
                    '
                </div>';
        }
        ?> 
</div>
<?php 
    echo $this->form()->closeTag(); 
}
```

My problem is that when I submit the form everything works perfect. The isValid function does what it has to and validates captcha correctly. But when I resend the same info via my browser refresh button, the isValid function returns true again which is not acceptable because the image has changed. It seems that old captcha is still valid to zf2 which is not correct and makes a security issue letting hackers easily bypass it. Am I missing something here?